# ¿Cómo resuelve mongoose los finds?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Al hacer un find con mongoose, me está devolviendo un array de objetos con el siguiente formato cada uno:

```
[{
   $__: InternalCache
   $__original_save: function () {}
   _doc: Object
   _posts: Object
   _pres: Object
   errors: undefined
   isNew: false
   save: function wrappedPointCut() {}
}]
```

La información del elemento está dentro del atributo _doc, y creo que en el find debería devolverme ese atributo como objeto sin los métodos.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal o es que realmente mongoose siempre devuelve toda esa información?

El find:

```
User.find().exec(function(err, users){
   //user
})
```

Comment: Sugerencia: agrega el pedazo de código donde haces el find, resumiendo los superficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es añadir el metodo [lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) al find:

```
User.find().lean().exec(function(err, users){
   //user
})
```

Ahora el objeto "users" tendrá el formato adecuado.